# How to use Android ViewSwitcher?

Tags: android, android-mapview, viewswitcher

I'm trying to use the ViewSwitcher to perform switches between two views. One is an ImageView and the other is a MapView. I have a button which the user clicks to perform this switch but my codes are causing an error. Do you guys have any idea what's about?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<linearlayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <relativelayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <imageview
            android:id="@+id/banner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignparenttop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/banner_location"
            android:clickable="false">
        </imageview>

        <linearlayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/banner"
            android:layout_centerhorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingbottom="5px">

            <imagebutton
                android:id="@+id/btnBusSvcs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginright="5px"
                android:layout_margintop="5px"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_bus_svcs">
            </imagebutton>

            <imagebutton
                android:id="@+id/btnDrvRoute"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginleft="5px"
                android:layout_margintop="5px"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_drv_route">
            </imagebutton>
        </linearlayout>

        <viewswitcher
            android:id="@+id/switcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imgViewBusSvcs"
            android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout01">

            <imageview
                android:id="@+id/imgViewBusSvcs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout01"
                android:layout_centerinparent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/bus_svcs"
                android:clickable="false">
            </imageview>

            <com.google.android.maps.mapview
                android:id="@+id/mapview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="300px"
                android:apikey="REMOVE MY API KEY"
                android:clickable="true">
            </com.google.android.maps.mapview>
        </viewswitcher>

        <imagebutton
            android:id="@+id/btnBackHome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignparentbottom="true"
            android:layout_centerhorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_back_to_home">
        </imagebutton>
    </relativelayout>
</linearlayout>
```

The error is as such

```
11-05 20:53:13.964: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.getRelatedView(RelativeLayout.java:694)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.getRelatedViewParams(RelativeLayout.java:708)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.applySizeRules(RelativeLayout.java:629)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:279)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7115)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2875)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:350)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7115)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2875)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7115)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:2875)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7115)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:698)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1482)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
11-05 20:53:13.995: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Really appreciate the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you setting Layout parameters at runtime or is everything in the XML?

Have you tried wrapping the two views of the ViewSwitcher each into its own LinearLayout?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the two views of the ViewSwitcher each into its own LinearLayout?

Comment: Hi, thanks! Your solution works but do you have any idea why is it required to wrap the two views with LinearLayouts in the ViewSwitcher? I couldn't find a good example of ViewSwitcher in the API, and nowhere is it documented in the API that this is required. Appreciate your help! :D

Comment: I guess it is a matter of computing the sizes of the views. But I'm just guessing, may not be correct.

Comment: it doesn't looks like answer at all.

Comment: Docs says  `A ViewSwitcher can only have two child views, of which only one is shown at a time.`

Comment: VincentMimoun-Prat and @fgs you should remove your comments because their presence defeats their purpose (they attract attention, the key is still present in revision history)

Answer (score 32):

Add the ViewSwitcher widget to your xml layout file.
to the ViewSwitcher add 2 new layouts.

```xml
<ViewSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/viewSwitcher1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left">
            
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:text="This is simplezdscsdc text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            
    </LinearLayout>
       
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:text="This issdsdsds simplezdscsdc text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        
    </LinearLayout>

</ViewSwitcher>
```

In your activity, add function to a button which switches between the views

```java
viewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher1);
myFirstView = findViewById(R.id.view1);
mySecondView = findViewById(R.id.view2);
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (viewSwitcher.getCurrentView() != myFirstView) {
            viewSwitcher.showPrevious(); 
        } else if (viewSwitcher.getCurrentView() != mySecondView) {                 
            viewSwitcher.showNext();
        }
    }
});
```

`android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left"` allows the view to scroll in from the left.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a LinearLayout wrapping everything else. On the example I see more than one but no main one.

Answer (score 0):

Your ImageView tag should fall under ViewSwitcher tag, just like the com.google.android.maps.MapView.