# DialogFragment with multiple fragments/views

Tags: android

How can I display a dialogfragment with multiple fragments one after the other with animation?

The use case I have is:

1. DialogFragment is showing with fragment 1. It has a "next" button
2. User clicks next
3. The same dialogFragment displays fragment 2 with a slide in animation.

Any pointers would help.

Thank you in advance.

This is the base dialogfragment I am using

```
public class BaseDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public BaseDialogFragment () {

    }

    public static BaseDialogFragment newInstance(String title) {
        BaseDialogFragment frag = new BaseDialogFragment ();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Here is how the behaviour is. It is BottomNavigation activity that is displaying dialog with flow. The next/previous dialog comes in with slide in/out navigation.

[image]

I am open to other suggestions too such as dialog-Themed activity

Comment: This question needs some love

Comment: Wheres your other layout?  where's your button clickhandler?

Comment: Also,  must you use an extra fragment for this? (have you seen this yet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13909796/794088 )

Comment: Use a ViewPager in the DialogFragment. Each element of the ViewPager can be different fragments(extending a base fragement). This give a lot of flexibility.

Comment: @petey,  no need for other layouts as this question is regardless of the layout. It is layout1 that takes you to layout 2 (or even layout3). It is like a workflow in dialog. If I use a viewswitcher then all the logic will be together and this is too clutered. I was hoping we can achieve this in different "containers" if you know what I mean

Comment: @Pellucide, Viewpager (as fas as I know) provides the swipe left/right. But in my case it shouldn't happen as it is not linear (clicking on different buttons changes the fragements accordingly and they shouldnt navigate based on swipe left/right

Comment: @Snake disable the swipes. created an example at
https://notabug.org/pellucide/dialogfragment.git

Comment: I added a flow. with a bit more text , what would be the "right" way for achieving this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as i understand, you would like to have one parent dialog fragment which is managing two child fragments.
To do so, you have to follow those steps.

1. Create parent dialog fragment
2. Create two child fragment
3. Add first fragment to parent fragment
4. Add call back from first child fragment to parent to replace it with second child fragment
5. Add functionality to parent fragment to replace child fragment

Lets start with first step. We are going to create a container dialog fragment:

```
class ContainerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Our container_fragment  xml will look like:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Then we create two child fragment:

```
class ChildFragment1 extends Fragment {
    //...the content is up to you...
}
```

and

```
class ChildFragment2 extends Fragment {
    //...the content is up to you...
}
```

We add first fragment to our container dialog fragment:

```
class ContainerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ChildFragment1 childFragment1 = new ChildFragment1();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, childFragment1);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Now we have to add an interface to communicate between parent and child fragment to replace it:

```
class ChildFragment1 extends Fragment {
    interface ChildFragment1Listener {
        void onButtonPressed();
    }

    //you have to call this method when user pressed to button
    void onButtonPressed() {
        ChildFragment1Listener listener = (ChildFragment1Listener) getParentFragment();
        listener.onButtonPressed();
    }
}
```

Finally, we have to implement this interface in our container dialog fragment and add replace functionality:

```
class ContainerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements ChildFragment1.ChildFragment1Listener {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ChildFragment1 childFragment1 = new ChildFragment1();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, childFragment1);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    void onButtonPressed() {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        //Out of simplicity, i am creating ChildFragment2 every time user presses the button. 
        //However, you should keep the instance somewhere to avoid creation.
        ChildFragment2 childFragment2 = new ChildFragment2();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, childFragment2);
        //You can add here as well your fragment in and out animation how you like.
        transaction.addToBackStack("childFragment2");
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Thats it.

Comment: That's amazing. Well deserved bounty :) . May I ask you a question. How can I handle the back button pressed so it goes back from childfragment2 to childfragment1? Because right now pressing the back button will just dismiss the whole dialog .

Comment: For this you have to add a key listener to dialog.
You can add `getDialog().setOnKeyListener` to container dialog fragment and catch back button press, then pop back stack.

Comment: As another option, since there is now a NavHostFragment to can use this.
Instead of <FrameLayout> use <FragmentContainerView>. In your ContainerDialogFragment you can use `childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment`  so you can navigate. In the children you can use the standard `findNavController()`. You can then setup the navigation in a dialog_navigation.xml.

Comment: why the activity that call the dialog ask me to implement the ChildFragment1Listener interface also? and than the  onButtonPressed() in the dialog don't called

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:

1) Create parent dialog fragment without any content

2) Create 3 Fragments representing each of the state of the dialog

3) Show content fragments and implement navigation between them in the context of ParentDialogFragment::childFragmentManager

Comment: It is point 3 that I am asking about. Can you show some code?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to have custom dialog fragments with animations by using normal fragments in the following way.

Add the id to the root layout of your activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

In your activity class retrieve `root_layout` with `findViewById()` and add the following method:

```
public void showFragment(BaseDialogFragment fragment, @AnimatorRes @AnimRes int enter,
                             @AnimatorRes @AnimRes int exit) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        String fragmentName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        if (manager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentName) == null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(enter, exit, enter, exit);
            transaction.add(R.id.root_layout, fragment, fragmentName);
            transaction.addToBackStack(fragmentName);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

Where `enter` and `exit` arguments accept xml anim files like `anim/slide_in.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="300" android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"/>
</set>
```

And  `anim/slide_out.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate android:duration="300" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"/>
</set>
```

Then create a base class for dialogs which allow to dismiss the dialog:

```
public abstract class BaseDialogFragment extends Fragment {

    public void dismiss() {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .popBackStack(getClass().getName(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

Back key is also working because the fragment is in the back stack.
Now create your dialogs extending from the `BaseDialogFragment` class and show them calling `showFragment(dialogFragment, R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);` from your activity.

If you have to start Dialog2 from Dialog1, simply use `((YourActivity)getActivity).showFragment(dialogFragment, R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out)`.

Comment: But according to your description, you are creating multiple dialogs here? Where I want to have one dialog with multiple fragments

Answer (score 1):

Search in Youtube "Fragment Tricks (Google I/O '17)" If you want to understand how it works.

Solution is simple `addToBackStack`

For animation: you can set your custom animation -> `transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.first, R.anim.second...)`;

I suggest to watch the google presentation, you will be amazed, hope so.