# Android : Fragments vs Stacked layouts

Tags: java, android

Say I have this layout file here. Which is more efficient and a better practice : To use a fragment or just a frame layout and toggle visibility? This is only an example. What if the use-case scaled significantly, which would be a better solution?[image]

Comment: To me, using a Fragment in this situation seems overkill. I would use a ViewSwitcher. Much simpler and no need to deal with all the lifecycle BS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106071/how-to-use-android-viewswitcher

Comment: As well as handling communication between fragments and activities implementing interfaces, etc. Are there any advantages tho?

Comment: Not that I can think of. I think it would just mean writing and maintaining more code.